# Pandas python how to transform nested JSON object into rows and columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json dictionary of thousands of json objects called 'businesses' that contains the following nested JSON in an array. Each 'business' has a 'unique-request-id' that comes back as well. Sometimes, one request could come back with multiple busineses.

```
{'principals': [{'addresses': [{'city': 'DENVILLE', 'state': 'NJ', 'metadata': {'sources': [], 'lastSeen': None, 'firstSeen': None, 'sourceCount': 0}, 'zip': '07834', 'address': '87 JILLOW AVE'}], 'titles': ['SECRETARY'], 'names': [{'suffix': None, 'firstName': 'JAMES', 'middleName': None, 'lastName': 'VU', 'salutation': None, 'pids': [], 'metadata': {'sources': [], 'lastSeen': None, 'firstSeen': None, 'sourceCount': 0}}, {'suffix': None, 'firstName': 'LAURA', 'middleName': 'A', 'lastName': 'VU', 'salutation': None, 'pids': [], 'metadata': {'sources': [], 'lastSeen': None, 'firstSeen': None, 'sourceCount': 0}}], 'pids': ['1000320219031584'], 'lastSeenDate': '2008-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'firstSeenDate': None}, {'addresses': [{'city': 'LAKE HAVASU CITY', 'state': 'AZ', 'metadata': {'sources': [], 'lastSeen': None, 'firstSeen': None, 'sourceCount': 0}, 'zip': '86403', 'address': '1887 WILLOW AVE'}], 'titles': ['MANAGER'], 'names': [{'suffix': None, 'firstName': 'JASON', 'middleName': None, 'lastName': 'ROBERTS', 'salutation': None, 'pids': [], 'metadata': {'sources': [], 'lastSeen': None, 'firstSeen': None, 'sourceCount': 0}}], 'pids': ['1000320147115755'], 'lastSeenDate': '1999-07-28T00:00:00.000Z', 'firstSeenDate': None}], 'tradeNames': ['DORI LAURA DVM'], 'addresses': [{'city': 'HAVASU CITY', 'state': 'NY', 'metadata': {'sources': [], 'lastSeen': None, 'firstSeen': None, 'sourceCount': 0}, 'zip': '16403', 'address': '299 PASEO DEL SOL'}], 'searchType': 'Name+Address', 'contacts': [], 'phones': ['19284532022'], 'registrationDate': '1999-07-29T00:00:00.000Z', 'websites': ['WWW.DORIVET.COM'], 'eid': '39281818', 'sources': {'sources': [], 'lastSeen': None, 'firstSeen': None, 'sourceCount': 5}, 'dataSource': 'iData', 'names': ['DORI VETERINARY CENTER INC', 'DORI-ROBERTS INC'], 'registrationAddress': {'city': 'PHOENIX', 'state': 'AZ', 'metadata': {'sources': [], 'lastSeen': None, 'firstSeen': None, 'sourceCount': 0}, 'zip': '85007', 'address': '1200 W WASHINGTON'}, 'duns': ['042512348'], 'relatedBusinesses': [], 'industryNames': ['VETERINARIAN, ANIMAL SPECIALTIES'], 'officeAddress': None, 'ein': ['77711133333']}
```

I would like the ultimate CSV from DataFrame to look like this ... with all the flattened columns to the right.

```
RequestId BusinessName                 BusinessAddress .... 
ABCD      DORI VETERINARY CENTER INC.  87 JILLOW AVENUE
ABCD      SECONDARY VETERINARY CENTER INC.   3 MAIN ST.
XYZV.     xxxbusiness                        20 AUTO ST.
```

Is this possible using Pandas and DataFrames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do something like below using `json_normalize`, the problem with this is, you'll have to do it separately for each record path - one for principals, one for tradeNames and so on.

```
with open('test-so.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df1 = json_normalize(data, 
                 record_path=['principals', 'addresses'], 
                 meta=[['principals', 'lastSeenDate']],
                 errors='ignore')

               city state    zip          address metadata.sources metadata.lastSeen metadata.firstSeen  metadata.sourceCount     principals.lastSeenDate
0          DENVILLE    NJ  07834    87 JILLOW AVE               []              None               None                     0  2008-01-01T00: 00: 00.000Z
1  LAKE HAVASU CITY    AZ  86403  1887 WILLOW AVE               []              None               None                     0  1999-07-28T00: 00: 00.000Z
```

Or you could use `flatten_json` directly, it flattens the entire json into one row, check the documentation here - [Flatten JSON](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten#usage-with-pandas)